# Microsoft.Speech Reference Missing C++/cli

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

I'm having a hard time finding any information on this so maybe someone here can enlighten me. I've coded a module in C++/Cli, everything is good, but for some reason in the reference list(When I right-click on the VS project to add a reference), I can't find Microsoft.Speech in the list.

There is another one that's equivalent, it's called System.Speech, but I absolutely need Microsoft.Speech. Since the module is pure managed code, shouldn't I have access to all the .NET modules? Or maybe there is a pack I can download to extend it?

Thanks.

## Update:

I'm referring to these two calls:

```
 using Microsoft.Speech.AudioFormat;
 using Microsoft.Speech.Recognition;
```

Which can be found in the Kinect SDK samples. I need those in C++/CLI because I cannot access the kinect's recognizer if I use the System native version.

Comment: There is no namespace in the .NET framework that is is named "Microsoft.Speech".  You are not going to find it in that dialog.  No idea what it might be.  If you know you need it then you shouldn't have any trouble describing *why* you think you need it.

Comment: Have you installed the Kinect SDK yet?  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=28782

Comment: And the Speech SDK?  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27226

Comment: I have both, my C++/CLI module currently captures the depth, color frames and skeleton buffer into our C++ app. I have, currently installed on my machine both the Kinect SDK and the Speech SDK. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution :

```
#using "Microsoft.Speech.dll"
using namespace Microsoft::Speech;
using namespace Microsoft::Speech::Recognition;
```

Everything now works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you are not able to find Microsoft.Speech.dll in the .NET tab, you can do the following:

Import Microsoft.Speech.dll from the following location:

```
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Speech\11.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Speech.dll
```